# Evaluating Double Integral over General Region

Tags: integration

We are given:

$$\iint_D (\cos(y^2)) \, \mathrm{d}A$$

where D is the region in the first quadrant bounded by the y-axis, the line $y = x$ and the line $y = 1$.

My first presumption is to graph $y=x$ and $y=1$. We know that $y=x$ is a slant between the $x-axis$ and $y-axis$ and $y=1$ is a horizontal function that for any $x$, $y=1$.

I setup the integrand as follows:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{y} (\cos(y^2)) \, \mathrm{dydx}$$

We can use parts to obtain

$$u = y^2$$
$$du = 2ydy$$
$$v=dy$$
$$dv = ydy$$

May I proceed or is this completely wrong?

Comment: Go for $x$ first. Then it's a substitution.

Comment: No, $\int_0^1 \int_0^y \cos(y^2) \ dx dy$

Comment: $\cos(y^2)$ is a constant w.r.t. $x$. what's the integral of a constant?

Comment: I think the new integrand becomes $$\int_{0}^{1} ycos(y^2) dy$$ which is easy to integrate, finitely. Therefore, I do not need parts.

Comment: Is the answer $1/2(sin1-sin0)$?